# Create random flashing dots in particular countries

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to show website usage statistics in a more graspable way. I'd like to use google maps API to have dots flash in random areas of a country every time someone in that country logs in.

My question is two part.

Firstly, is there a built in way to create a dot on google maps without using overlays, or with an overlay that will delete itself after a given period of time (say 25ms)?

Second, is there a way to generate random coordinates that will be used to generate the dot? The difficulty that I'm having is that I need to make sure it stays within the country that the user logged in and it needs to be in a plausible location. It'll be pretty obvious that it's a made up location if it continually shows usage in the water.

I could create a file with millions of coordinates for each country and have it randomly draw from that file, but I'm trying to avoid that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

interesting use case:)

"is there a built in way to create a dot on google maps without using overlays, or with an overlay that will delete itself after a given period of time (say 25ms)?"

I recommend just creating the overlay and using jquery (or whatever framework you use) to do a nice animate to slowly hide the overlay. Once hidden you can remove it ($(".theelementselector').remove())

As to your second question: 
Lot's of ways to go about this, one of the best imho would be:

- get your hands on polygon data of countries (tip: www.weogeo.com for free downloads on request)
- given a boundingbox of the country
- generate a random point in the bounding box (for instance with the so called ["monte carlo method."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method))
- check if it's in the polygon as well (point polygon intersect. Look it up on SO for example)

hth

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Can you please explain polygon data to me? I'm not sure what it is and google isn't being much help.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon . A polygon is a mathematical representation of lines forming a plane. In this case each polygon represents the circumference of a country. When you have this data with some math you can calculate if a point is inside or outside the country. A quick way to get a random point is to draw a rectangle around the polygon that is as small as possible (a so called boundingbox) and generate a point inside of that using the aforementioned Monte Carlo technique. Do some follow up questions for other parts of the puzzle you struggle with. hth.